# MeshLab : How to achieve the information of each component

Tags: meshlab

**What am I going to do?**

I have a stl file which has two connected components.

[image: img1]

I am trying to calculate the volume, surface and curvatures of each component.

**What's my question?**

1. How to identify which vertices or facets belong to each component?
   I noticed MeshLab can identify the number of components, which seems each component has a ID. Hence, the vertices and facets should be related to each component(ID).
2. How to calculate the volume and surface of each component?
   The filter "Compute Geometric Measures" can calculate the whole volume, but how to calculate the volume of each component?

Thanks for your help.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the layer and select "Split in connected components" then use geometric measures on each component.